# How to set property calue of bean as a value getting returned from method of another class?

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on one of the task in Hybris where i need to fetch the value of attribute from one class "a" to class "b" when my bean for class b is called. Below is what i tried. "i am on one page where i selected 10 products and on calling multi select event listener i got number of products in class a." but when bean is initialised for class b there i am getting null instead of value i need from class a.

```
Class A{

private string test;
public void setTest(String test)
{
this.test=test}        //value is setting up on an event like 
                            multi-select of products
public String getTest()
{
return test;} .                      //value is coming here
}

Class B{
private String attribute;
public void setAttribute(String attribute)         //getting null
{
this.attribute=attribute}
public String getAttribute()
{
return attribute;}

}


<bean id="classB" class"B">
<property name="attribute">
<bean factory-bean="A" factory-method="getTest"></bean>
</bean>
```

Comment: reformat your question in order to be readable. to do so check the rules of the community

Comment: ...and add the related Hybris content. Currently, we see just a Class A and B with no dependency in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two separate beans for **class A** and **class B** as there is no dependency in both the classes as I understood from your problem statement.

After that, inject **class A as property in class B** will solve your issue.